# Why cable TV frequency range ends at 1 GHz?

Tags: frequency, cables, high-frequency, tv, bandwidth

Currently frequencies 50-1000 MHz are allocated for TV and data transfers. I understand why there are limitations for aerial or satellite transmissions, but why are they retained for cable transmissions? If a cable provider streams something only through RF cable network, why can't he use whatever frequencies he wants, higher than 1 GHz (ensuring that customers have correct receivers)?

Comment: I suspect the answer is going to involve (a) licensing of cable companies and (b) transmission line properties of the physical cable used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One factor (but not the only one) is certainly "plant leakage".

Plant in this case means the "cable plant" which is an odd term, but like a factory is also known as a plant, the installed base of copper and cable is also an asset and is called plant.  Very strange.

Because there is so much cable plant in a system, they try to keep the costs down, all cables will leak RF and the higher the frequency the greater the chance.  They have to decide on a cut off point, and trade off against cost.  With more shielding and better connectors costing more.

Hopefully someone else will chime in with other reasons, perhaps historical, amplifier limitations perhaps.

Comment: Perhaps, but I suspect leakage at higher frequencies would be in general less likely to cause problematic interference to radio services.  More likely, attenuation and technology limitations (both present, and and inherited from past implementations) are the cause.

Comment: Which is why cable companies occasionally put traps on customer lines to minimize signal leakage.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, Leakage at high frequencies might not be a radio interference issue, but it does prevent the signal getting to the paying customer.

Comment: @Passerby - but what frequencies are they trapping?